# How to implement importance weight sampling for a DQN in Pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am attempting to implement PER (Prioritized Experience Replay) along with a DQN algorithm that I've written from scratch. I've been able to solve OpenAI's cartPole-v0 environment with my DQN algorithm without PER. After implementing PER, the algorithm no longer converges. I suspect that the issue comes in when I try to anneal the bias introduced by PER with importance sampling weights. The algoritm I am trying to implement can be found on page 5 of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.05952.pdf) paper.

This is the function that is supposed to update the neural network at every iteration of the simulation:

```
    def learn(self):

        self.beta = max(self.beta, self.step_count/self.epochs)
        if self.beta >= 1:
            self.beta = 1

        # Sample random transitions
        samples = self.memory.sample(self.batch_size, self.beta)
        indexes = np.array(samples['indexes'])
        weights = samples['weights']

        states = self.memory.data['state'][indexes]
        actions = self.memory.data['action'][indexes]
        rewards = self.memory.data['reward'][indexes]
        terminal = self.memory.data['done'][indexes]
        next_states = self.memory.data['next_state'][indexes]

        states = torch.tensor(
            states, dtype=torch.float32).to(self.Q_net.device)
        actions = torch.tensor(
            actions, dtype=torch.int64).unsqueeze(-1).to(self.Q_net.device)
        rewards = torch.tensor(
            rewards, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(-1).to(self.Q_net.device)
        terminal = torch.tensor(
            terminal, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(-1).to(self.Q_net.device)
        next_states = torch.tensor(
            next_states, dtype=torch.float32).to(self.Q_net.device)

        targets = self.T_net.forward(next_states)
        targets = rewards[0] + self.gamma * \
            torch.max(targets, dim=1)[0] * (1-terminal)[0]

        targets = targets.unsqueeze(1)
        Q_s = self.Q_net.forward(states)
        Q_s = torch.gather(input=Q_s, dim=1, index=actions)

        priorities = (targets - Q_s).detach().numpy()
        for i in range(len(priorities)):
            priorities[i] = np.abs(priorities[i]) + self.min_sampling_prob
        self.memory.update_priorities(indexes, priorities)

        weights = torch.tensor(
            weights, dtype=torch.float32).to(self.Q_net.device)

        weights = torch.reshape(weights, targets.shape)

        loss = nn.functional.smooth_l1_loss(weights*Q_s, targets)

        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()

        self.optimizer.step()
```

And here is the testing script:

```
from environment import FullEnvironment
from dqn_agent_per import Agent
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gym

env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')

EPOCHS = 800

agent = Agent(env, alpha=0.5, beta=0.5, eps_start=1.0, hidden_nodes=512, batch_size=64, epochs=EPOCHS, gamma=0.999, eps_decay=0.996,
              eps_min=0.1, lr=(5e-4), custom_env=False, activation='r')

eps_hist = []
avg_score = []
scores = []
TARGET_UPDATE_FREQ = 100
total_steps = 0
for i in range(EPOCHS):

    state = env.reset()
    episode_reward = 0.0
    steps = 0

    while True:
        total_steps += 1
        action = agent.choose_action(state)
        state_next, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
        agent.store_transition(state, action, reward, state_next, done)
        agent.learn()
        episode_reward += reward
        state = state_next
        if total_steps % TARGET_UPDATE_FREQ == 0:
            agent.reset_target_network()
        if done:
            break

    eps_hist.append(agent.epsilon)
    avg_score.append(episode_reward)
    scores.append(np.mean(avg_score[-100:]))
    agent.decay_eps()
    print('Episode', i, 'score %.2f' % episode_reward, 'Avg score %.2f' %
          np.mean(avg_score[-100:]), 'Epsilon %.3f' % agent.epsilon)

plt.plot(scores)
plt.show()
```

Thank you very much in advance!